# Filter list in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I have two domain classes.

```
class BillingServiceGroup
{
    Integer billingServiceGroupCode
    String billingServiceGrpDesc
    String status // ACTIVE or INACTIVE
}

class ServiceGroup
{
    String serviceGroupName
    String description
    BillingServiceGroup billingServiceGroup
}
```

when i view the `serviceGroup` page. it shows list of all `billingServiceGroup`, but my requirement is that only the rows having `status == ACTIVE` can be displayed in the list.

so i have to filter the list based on the value of status. can anyone provide some code to implement this logic?

Comment: Why is your `status` field not a `boolean` or an `enum` type? It'd make things easier for you.

Comment: I have changed status to enum type.                              enum Status{
  ACTIVE(true),
  INACTIVE(false)

  private boolean bool

  public Status(boolean bool){
   this.bool = bool
  }
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`withCriteria`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html):

```
ServiceGroup.withCriteria {
    billingServiceGroup {
        eq('status', 'ACTIVE')
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but where we have to use this code??In domain class or some where else?

Comment: @AB - I'm not following you there. How are your controllers and views set up? Are you just using the scaffolding? If so, you'll probably have to `generate-all` for your `ServiceGroup` domain and modify the generated controller's `list` action.

Answer (score 1):

The [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying) contains a [section on querying associations](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying) using the `where` method.